# Fixed position table header extends off the screen

Tags: html, css, html-table, flexbox, overflow

I have a layout with a fixed top header, fixed left sidebar, and scrollable right content area. The content includes a long table that I would like to scroll underneath a sticky header.

I've created a separate table just for the header purposes, and before I add any fixed-position style to it everything lines up fine. When I put position-fixed, the header sticks but it extends off the screen (probably due to the offset of the sidebar?) Is there any way to have it extend to the full width of the screen like the table itself? Here is the fiddle, I have a comment on the line thats causing problems in the CSS:

https://jsfiddle.net/7wgnosr1/14/

```css
body,
html {
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

.container {
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

header {
  z-index: 0;
  flex: 0 64px;
  display: flex;
  background: #f4991a;
}

main {
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  background: #f9f5f0;
  overflow: auto;
}

aside {
  background: #f2ead3;
  flex: 0 0 300px;
  overflow: auto;
  order: 0;
  border-right: 1px solid #d9d9d9;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

section {
  background: #f3f3f5;
  flex: 1 1 100px;
  order: 1;
  overflow: auto;
}

table.fixed {
  position: fixed;
  /* If I comment this out, it aligns correctly but does not stick */
}

table {
  text-align: left;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <header>
    Fixed Header
  </header>
  <main>
    <aside>
      Fixed Sidebar
    </aside>
    <section>
      <table class="fixed">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Fixed TH 1</th>
            <th>Fixed TH 2</th>
            <th>Fixed TH 3</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
      </table>
      <table>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </section>
  </main>
</div>
```

```
<table class="fixed"> // with position fixed, it sticks but extends off the screen
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Fixed TH 1</th>
      <th>Fixed TH 2</th>
      <th>Fixed TH 3</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
</table>
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>3</td>
    </tr>
    ... lots more rows
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Do note [the varying support for `position:sticky`, especially on table elements](https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-sticky) however.

Comment: Note, with your current example 1st row in the 2nd table is invisible.

Comment: I looked into position:sticky but unfortunately it didn't work on my version of Chrome (63). Sadly I can't count on something that chrome doesn't  handle

Comment: Take a look at my updated answer about `position: sticky`

Comment: are you sure you tested the right fiddle ? https://jsfiddle.net/7wgnosr1/34/ and also noticed top coordonates and position:relative added to parent ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest to use nested flexbox layout, no fixed position is needed.

Added a div container around the second table. Also set `table-layout: fixed;` for equal width cells even if content has different length.

```
<section>
  <table>
    ...
  </table>
  <div class="scroll-area">
    <table>
      ...
    </table>
  </div>
</section>
```

---

```
section {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

table {
  table-layout: fixed;
  width: 100%;
}

.scroll-area {
  flex: 1;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

---

```css
body,
html {
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

.container {
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

header {
  z-index: 0;
  flex: 0 64px;
  display: flex;
  background: #f4991a;
}

main {
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  background: #f9f5f0;
  overflow: auto;
}

aside {
  background: #f2ead3;
  flex: 0 0 300px;
  overflow: auto;
  order: 0;
  border-right: 1px solid #d9d9d9;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

section {
  background: #f3f3f5;
  flex: 1 1 100px;
}

section {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

table {
  text-align: left;
  table-layout: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: white;
}

.scroll-area {
  flex: 1;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<header>
  Fixed Header
</header>
<main>
  <aside>
    Fixed Sidebar
  </aside>
  <section>
    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Fixed TH 1</th>
          <th>Fixed TH 2</th>
          <th>Fixed TH 3</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
    </table>
    <div class="scroll-area">
      <table>
        <tbody>
          <tr><td>1 first cell</td><td>2</td><td>3</td></tr>
          <tr><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td></tr>
          <tr><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td></tr>
          <tr><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td></tr>
          <tr><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td></tr>
          <tr><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td></tr>
          <tr><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td></tr>
          <tr><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td></tr>
          <tr><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td></tr>
          <tr><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td></tr>
          <tr><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td></tr>
          <tr><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td></tr>
          <tr><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td></tr>
          <tr><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td></tr>
          <tr><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td></tr>
          <tr><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td></tr>
          <tr><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td></tr>
          <tr><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td></tr>
          <tr><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td></tr>
          <tr><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td></tr>
          <tr><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td></tr>
          <tr><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td></tr>
          <tr><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td></tr>
          <tr><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td></tr>
          <tr><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td></tr>
          <tr><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td></tr>
          <tr><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td></tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  </section>
</main>
</div>
```

Comment: So this looks very promising because I don't need to care about the width of the sidebar.. Is there an explanation somewhere on how this is working? I'm having a hard time understanding why it sticks..

Comment: See this https://jsfiddle.net/zh5rhdfk/ a small version of it and read the comments.

Comment: I ended up choosing this solution because it didn't require the calc, I didn't have to worry about sticky support, and the scrollbar doesn't show alongside the header. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Actually, everything works as it should, because according to docs fixed elements are positioned relative to the browser window, and the header of your table have a width equal to the windows's one. If your sidebar are going to always have a fixed width (300px for example) you can set a restriction for the table header like so:

```
table.fixed {
  position: fixed;
  max-width: calc(100% - 300px);
}
```

**Update:** As was mentioned in the comments `position: sticky` is coming. Google Chrome [56+](https://youtu.be/F4DfGVbvRpY) supports it for `th` elements and other modern browsers [already started to go in this direction](https://caniuse.com/#search=sticky). You said that it didn't work for you on Chrome 63. Did you set a threshold properly? Setting just `position: sticky` is not enough:

```css
body,
html {
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

.container {
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

header {
  z-index: 0;
  flex: 0 64px;
  display: flex;
  background: #f4991a;
}

main {
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  background: #f9f5f0;
  overflow: auto;
}

aside {
  background: #f2ead3;
  flex: 0 0 300px;
  overflow: auto;
  order: 0;
  border-right: 1px solid #d9d9d9;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

section {
  background: #f3f3f5;
  flex: 1 1 100px;
  order: 1;
  overflow: auto;
}

table {
  text-align: left;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: white;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

th {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  background-color: #fff;
}

td, th {
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

  <header>
    Fixed Header
  </header>
  <main>
    <aside>
      Fixed Sidebar
    </aside>
    <section>
      <table>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Fixed TH 1</th>
            <th>Fixed TH 2</th>
            <th>Fixed TH 3</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </section>
  </main>

</div>
```

Comment: sticky is buggy in FF when applied to table children elements (your example fails in firefox), my earlier comment with https://jsfiddle.net/7wgnosr1/34/ worked when sticky was applied to the table and when parent is set to relative position (to match top coordonates) .

Comment: @G-Cyr FF will be updated soon. Accordingly to [caniuse.com](https://caniuse.com/#search=sticky) dev. branch have this fixed. I believe users will get the update within a month or so. Anyway it is still a very new feature and should be used with caution. It is not always a public website when we use html/css. Could be a small project for one or a few people. They can use the latest Chrome or FF if it is needed.

Comment: This is a known bug for years already, it will indeed be fixed once ;)

Comment: Well now I don't know which direction to go haha. The calc worked but I don't like having to know the sidebar width, sticky works but I don't know if the support is there, and the nested flexbox layout in the other answer also looks promising. How to choose!